# Windows Phone 8 Emulator Deployment Issue with Internet

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am facing an issue with windows 8 phone emulator.

> Windows Phone emulator wasnt able to connect to Windows Phone
>   operating system. Phone didnt respond to connect request

This is the error that I get. When the emulator starts with internet but my application doesnot deploy. The ip that gets assigned is `192.168.137.1`. Previously it worked fine, 
but then suddenly it started giving this issue.

Below is the list of troubleshooting that I have performed:

1. `169.254.xxx.xxx`  address set to internal emulator via dhcp, Application deployed successfully with NO internet connection
2. Have tried MAC address spoofing but nothing works when I use these settings.
3. Have changed External Virtual Switch in Sharing mode this starts the internet with ip  `192.168.137.1` but application doesnot deploy
   In debugger errors shown are:

> ```
> Invalid pointer error
> App deployment failed
> ```

1. Have tried Network bridging but still it doesnt work.
2. Created all settings manually including the internal switch and external swithch. But same issue faced when it gets `192.168.137.1` ip then internet works but application doesnt deploy.
   And when it gets  `169.254.xxx.xxx` ip series application deploys but no internet connection.
3. No firewall are turned on or no antivirus is blocking any connections.
4. Wireless router used for network connectivity, still not successfully
5. Have also tried clean installation of everything but still no go.

Need help with this issue as I have been trying to get it resolved since a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not faced if installation is done on the same pc through a virtual machine.
What I did was :

> Have allotted 4gb ram, 60gb hdd & 4 cores to the VM.
>
> 1)I installed a virtual machine with default settings.
>
> 2)Then I stopped your virtual machine (shut Windows 8 down, DO NOT suspend it).
>
> 3)At the VMWare Virtual Machine list, right click Windows 8 machine then click "Show in Finder".
>
> 4)Right click the file then click "Show package contents", then find and open with a text editor a file with the extension .vmx
>
> 5)Go till the end of the file and add this two lines (first check whether they were previously added):
>
> > hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
> >
> > vhv.enable = "TRUE"
>
> 6)At the VMWare Virtual Machine list, right click Windows 8, click "Preferences" then "Advanced". Choose "Intel VT-X with EPT" as "Preferred virtualization engine".

And then when I started the windows in the virtual machine it seems to be working fine without any additional setting change. However it is still not running on a physical machine

I recommend if someone is facing a similar issue then to use a Virtual Machine till this kind of issue is resolved.

Comment: please which virtual machine do i need to install on windows 8?

Comment: You can use vmware or Virtualbox. Both work fine as tested by me.

Comment: I used to Hyper-v machine. but didn't get **Show in Finder** option. do there other way so that emulator can have internet?

Comment: In this method we are not using hyper v machines. We are creating different setup through vmware. This is since hyperv was launched we faced many issues. Hyper-v gives many issues with networking point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with the same problem for 3 days I finally solved my issue by disabling windows firewall for "Guest or public network". I have yet to figure out what application/service to allow through so I can re-enable it.