# Windows Phone 8 Emulator- Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am using Visual Studio 2012 in Windows 8. I have set up Windows Phone 8 sdk and everything was working fine until I made some changes to network settings. First I was unable to connect to internet through the emulator. But I managed to set up internet connectivity by sharing the physical connection with my USB modem. However now I'm having problems in launching the emulator which has been working absolutely fine before. When I run the emulator separately (via Hyper-V manager) everything is okay and I can connect to internet but the problem is when I launch the emulator from Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

[image]

A related question can be found here [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6DS6.jpg)] but the answer is not what I am looking for. Is there a way to fix this issue without running the emulator on a virtual machine?

Thanks

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6DS6.jpg) [Windows Phone 8 Emulator Deployment Issue with Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319282/windows-phone-8-emulator-deployment-issue-with-internet)

Comment: Same problem before. In my case, its Internet Connection is blocked by Norton Anti-Virus.

Comment: I don't think it's the problem this time. I've deactivated my AV (Avast) but the result is the same

Comment: I am not able to see your image description but i fetch this type of problem before..please reffere this link may be help you...     http://superuser.com/questions/552049/enabling-slat-correct-cant-start-windows-phone-emulator-error

Comment: if possible than upload image so i can understand very well

Comment: image URLs for those who have problems viewing them:
[Image 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I6DS6.jpg) , [Image 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq4EU.jpg)

Comment: @Tharindu Rusira  Please Help me for solving this issue. I've also covered with this problem. please sir help me.

Comment: @user2160008, I couldn't resolve the issue yet. Sorry. What about the following answers? Didn't you try any of them?

Comment: @Tharindu Rusira i tried but not solved. i am using Hyper-v machine.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this it was caused by my anti-virus software. Specifically, the 'AVG network filter driver' was enabled for the Hyper-V virtual adapter. Unchecking this option fixed the problem for me.

[Interference from other virtualization or networking software and drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_interference) outlines specifically which items should be checked for the virtual adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger runs over a TCP/IP connection so if you've changed the HyperV network settings it's possible you've isolated the VM from the host so it cannot open a connection. Try and reset the connection back to it was before you changed it to get the Internet working and this should re-store your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .VMX file in your virtual machine folder

```
vhv.enable = "TRUE"
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = “FALSE”
```

and save it.

Comment: I think you're explaining the scenario when we run the emulator in a virtual machine. Ain't you? But as per to my question above, I'm trying to run emulator on my physical host without any virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but I had to face the same problem and found this solution (all the other solutions didn't work for me)

1.go to network and sharing center

2.go to change adapter setting

3.go to v Ethernet (internal Ethernet port windows phone emulator internal switch)

4.right click it and enable it(if already enabled then disable and enable it again).